# score error while creating model in python

Tags: python, svm

I was using classification report to check the accuracy and also the confusion matrix

Comment: `there is an error` [What is your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some modifications to the code and it seems to work now

```
x = np.array([17, 17.083333, 17.166667, 17.25, 17.333333, 17.416667]) 
x = x.reshape(6,1) 
y = [1,0,1,1,0,1] 
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.20) 
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear') 
clf.fit(X_train,y_train) 
pred = clf.predict(X_test) 
score= sk.metrics.accuracy_score(y_test,pred) 
report = sk.metrics.classification_report (y_test, pred, target_names = ['0','1']) 
confusionmatrix = sk.metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test,pred) 

print ("Accuracy_Score: "+str(score))
print ("Classification_Report:\n"+report)
print ("Confusion_Matrix:")
print (confusionmatrix)
```

output:

Accuracy_Score: 0.5 
Classification_Report:
               precision   recall   f1-score    support

```
      0       0.00      0.00      0.00         1
      1       0.50      1.00      0.67         1
```

avg / total       0.25      0.50      0.33         2

Confusion_Matrix:
[[0 1]
 [0 1]]

I changed the input "x" to an numpy array and removed values from x.reshape and also you had a typo in clf.predict() you have given "Xtest" it has to be "X_test".

Hope this helps

Comment: I copied the exact same code as you have provided but this is the output I got

Accuracy_Score: 0.0
Classification_Report:
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.00      0.00      0.00         2
           1       0.00      0.00      0.00         0

   micro avg       0.00      0.00      0.00         2
   macro avg       0.00      0.00      0.00         2
weighted avg       0.00      0.00      0.00         2

Confusion_Matrix:
[[0 2]
 [0 0]]

and same error

Comment: you just have 6 examples and you are again splitting them into train and test i.e you are training with 4 examples...try adding more examples and also I changed the line in my previous post, it should be clf.fit(X_train,y_train) not clf.fit(x,y) .

Comment: Thanks . Now it shows the accuracy .70 for my new data. I replaced the x values and y values by adding 1550 more rows to it ( which was the actual data those 6 were just a part of it)
 precision    recall  f1-score   support
0       0.71      1.00      0.83       440
1       0.00      0.00      0.00       180

this is the output but I am not sure why is it 0.000 for '1' and "Precision and F-score are ill-defined and being set to 0.0" is still shown

Comment: that means your model misclassified all the examples for class '1'. seems like the dataset is imbalanced since its shows 180 examples belongs to class "1" and 440 examples belongs to class "0". if the dataset is not imbalanced try decreasing the test_set size. do some EDA to understand the data, play with different parameters for the model and also explore different algorithms